# how to run servicemix 3.3.2 with spring 4 su component?

Tags: spring, hibernate, apache-servicemix

Would like to check if `service mix 3.3.2` can support `spring 4` + `hibernate 4` ? what is the configuration need to be done? kindly assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceMix 3.3.x is EOL and it does not support Spring 4.

Comment: thanks for your response... I believe even service mix 4 is doesn't support Spring 4 as well. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: ServiceMix will support Spring 4, when Karaf supports it, which will happen in a future Karaf release. So its on the roadmap.